# ChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse and handleChallenge functions are not working in worklight

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

This is my js code. In this two functions are working, one is ChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse and another one is  ChallengeHandler.handleChallenge

Here i am creating challengeHandler for "sampleAppRealm" for security reasons using FormBasedAuthenticator

Here i used HTTP adapter procedure named as "getValidate()". This procedure is working without securityTest but with securityTest, it is not working...

i dont know where going wrong.. i am in lot of confusion

i am using worklight version 7.0
and jquery version 1.11
and jquery mobile 1.4.5

**My js code:**

```js
<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("Hi");
       });
       function getValidate(){
        alert();
        var invocationData = {
      adapter : 'Go2needsHTTP',
      procedure : 'getValidate',
      parameters : []
     };
     var options = {
      onSuccess : getValidateSuccess,
      onFailure : getValidateFailure,
      invocationContext: {}
     };
     WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
       }
       function getValidateSuccess(){
        alert("Success");
       }
       function getValidateFailure(){
        alert("Failure");
       }
       var SampleAppRealmChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("SampleAppRealm");  
       sampleAppRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
        alert(response);
        if (!response || response.responseText === null) {
            return false;
        }
        var indicatorIdx = response.responseText.search('j_security_check');
        
        if (indicatorIdx >= 0){
      return true;
     }  
     return false;
    }; 
    sampleAppRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response) {
     alert("handleChallenge");
        $('#AppDiv').hide();
        $('#AuthDiv').show();
        $('#AuthPassword').val('');
    };
    $(function(){
     $('#AuthSubmitButton').bind('click', function () {
      alert("AuthSubmitButton");
         var reqURL = '/j_security_check';
         var options = {};
         options.parameters = {
             j_username : $('#AuthUsername').val(),
             j_password : $('#AuthPassword').val()
         };
         options.headers = {};        sampleAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginForm(reqURL, options, sampleAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback);
     });
    });
    $(function(){
     $('#AuthCancelButton').bind('click', function () {
      alert("AuthCancelButton");
         sampleAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
         $('#AppDiv').show();
         $('#AuthDiv').hide();
     });
    });
      </script>
```

This is my html code:

**My html code:**

```html
<div data-role="page" id="page">
       <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
        <div id="AppDiv">
      <input type="button" id="getSecretDataButton" value="Call protected adapter proc" onclick="getValidate()" />
      <input type="button" class="appButton" value="Logout" onclick="WL.Client.logout('SampleAppRealm',{onSuccess: WL.Client.reloadApp})" />
      <div id="ResponseDiv"></div>
     </div>
        <div id="AuthDiv" style="display: block;">
      <p id="AuthInfo"></p>
      <div id="loginForm">
       <input type="text"`enter code here` id="AuthUsername" placeholder="Enter username" />
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <input type="password" id="AuthPassword" placeholder="Enter password" />
       <br/>
       <input type="button" id="AuthSubmitButton" onclick="WL.Client.Login('SampleAppRealm');" class="formButton" value="Login" />
       <input type="button" id="AuthCancelButton" class="formButton" value="Cancel" />
      </div>
     </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

This is my **authenticationConfig.xml** file:

```html
<customSecurityTest name="SampleAppRealm-securityTest"> <test realm="SampleAppRealm" isInternalUserID="true"/></customSecurityTest> <loginModule name="StrongDummy" expirationInSeconds="-1"> <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className> </loginModule> <realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy"> <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className> </realm>
```

This is my **HTTPadapter** prodedure:

```html
<procedure name="getValidate" securityTest="SampleAppRealm-securityTest"></procedure>
```

Just test and tell where i am doing wrong unable to find out the error.
Please help me....

Comment: What did not work? Error messages? Expected behavior? Actual behavior? Please go into a lot more details.

Comment: No error messages, the controller is not going to the above code that is ChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse is not working. This happens in #worklight environment. Please help me...

Comment: I edited above code. Please find it

Comment: Can you also include the authenticationConfig? And check the dev tool console in chrome, and the error console in eclipse.

Comment: <customSecurityTest name="SampleAppRealm-securityTest">
         <test realm="SampleAppRealm" isInternalUserID="true"/></customSecurityTest>    
<loginModule name="StrongDummy" expirationInSeconds="-1">
   <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
  </loginModule>
<realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy">
<className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
</realm>

Comment: I edited in Qsn also...

Comment: Hello @Nathan H please respond to my qsn please....

Comment: I don't work around the clock.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93786/discussion-between-edukondalu-thaviti-and-nathan-h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are saying that `isCustomResponse` does not get triggered at all? Your `alert` does not appear?

In this case, I think the error is very simple:

You declared: `var SampleAppRealmChallengeHandler = ...`

And then you set `sampleAppRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = ...`

Notice the first one is a capital `S` while the second one is a lower-case `s`.
Javascript is case-sensitive. If you declare a variable one way, you need to keep using the exact same casing everywhere.

Comment: Thank you so much @Nathan H ... that silly error did great problem. Thank you so much...